# React JSX ListItem Key concat

Tags: reactjs, jsx

To modularize my app I am dynamically creating lists. The data is displaying fine, however, I cannot achieve unique list item ids. I am attempting to set the key as the array item being mapped concatenated with a prop.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header as='h3'>{this.props.data['Day'+this.props.day]}</Header>
        <ul>
          {this.props.cities.map((park) => <li key={park+this.props.day}>{park} {this.props.data[park+'Day'+this.props.day+'PrecipPercent']}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
}
```

I am calling the Component via this snippet

```
let eachDay = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.days; i++) {
      eachDay.push(<MultiParkDetails cities={this.state.sortedCities} data={this.state.weatherData} cols={5} day={i}></MultiParkDetails>);
    }
return ({eachDay})
```

Comment: Could you post here what does your `cities` array look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use the index of array as key, it will always be unique. Use this:

```
let eachDay = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.days; i++) {
      eachDay.push(<MultiParkDetails key={i} cities={this.state.sortedCities} data={this.state.weatherData} cols={5} day={i}></MultiParkDetails>);
    }
return ({eachDay})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you need to be adding the key to the component itself where its being created and pushed into the array.

```
let eachDay = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.days; i++) {
      eachDay.push(<MultiParkDetails key={ uniqueKeyGoesHere} cities={this.state.sortedCities} data={this.state.weatherData} cols={5} day={i}></MultiParkDetails>);
    }
return ({eachDay})
```

You dont put the key in the individual component, you declare it when you actually are pushing them into an array through map or in this case using the for each loop.

Reviewing your answer you do have it correct here:

```
{this.props.cities.map((park) => <li key={park+this.props.day}>{park} {this.props.data[park+'Day'+this.props.day+'PrecipPercent']}</li>)}
```

as long the value concatenated is unique. If you get any warnings afte that please post them here. You would get one of two warnings, one being that you didn't set a key where one was needed and second would be a warning saying duplicate keys were found meaning you didn't use unique enough of a key.

For more information on keys can see facebook docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys